# Does the pointer get from sqlite3_column_blob() method need to be delete?

Tags: c, sqlite

Like this: const void * test = sqlite3_column_blob(stat, 1);
Can I delete or delete[] test?

Answer (score 8):

From the [sqllite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html):

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically. **Do not pass the pointers returned by sqlite3_column_blob() into sqlite3_free().**

Answer (score 0):

Look at its API Manual. If it is a C API, you probably have to `free` it. If it doesn't provide its own function like sqlite3_free (pcre does this for example), you have to use that function.

What you can't do is delete it using C++'s delete operator, since you have got a void pointer. You cannot delete a void pointer, since the compiler has to know about its type. (and void is an incomplete type. you can't delete incomplete types either).